# M2E - web project where are stored the options about target?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I m trying to repair the Eclipse Maven Web project, where after some build the folder 
disappeared.
I get: target/classes and target/generated sources folder, but no 
/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources, what suppose to be there according to settings(see below)

I can not solve the problem from any menu in "properties", so i looked at the config files of the project.
The project name is TomkatFromArchetype.
I searched in this forum for solution and checked my settings files like:

/.metadata/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.pageflow is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pageflow:Pageflow xmlns:pageflow="http://www.sybase.com/suade/pageflow" id="pf15021503419240" configfile="/TomkatFromArchetype/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml"/>
```

in /.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component must be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="TomkatFromArchetype">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java2"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="TomkatFromArchetype"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/TomkatFromArchetype/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

So you can see, the entry

```
 <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
```

is there, as mentioned in the topic
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202253/eclipse-tomcat-how-to-specify-which-folder-is-served-from-the-project)

also /.settings/.jsdtscope (maybe it is important) is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/webapp" />
    <classpathentry excluding="**/bower_components/*|**/node_modules/*|**/*.min.js"
        kind="src" path="target/m2e-wtp/web-resources" />
    <classpathentry kind="con"
        path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" />
    <classpathentry kind="con"
        path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.WebProject">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="hide" value="true" />
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con"
        path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.baseBrowserLibrary" />
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="" />
</classpath>
```

Is there other config files, what are related to the question or how else must i set it properly?

Thie web file are strangely located now in :
workspaceEclipse.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\TomkatFromArchetype\

Comment: If this is a Maven project, isn't the `pom.xml` the authoritative source for all of this? And btw, `.jsdtscope` is only for pointing out `.js` files for the tools, and does not influence the copying of resources.

Comment: no, now as you said i looked in pom.xml and didnt find for example deployment assembly options.
Some strange thing happensnow: int the target folder, there  is no web ressources , howewer this runs in tomcat fine

Comment: i found possible reason for that:
as creating a new web project, adding content and some strange error 
appears like "can not change project facets to version 3.0" if it is originaly set to "2.3",
there were a "solution" is this forum, to disable the Dynamic web module facet and maven ->update . The error realy "dissapears", but after that, oder because of interation with tomcat7-maven-plugin, the m2e-wtp dissapears and the web sources are stored in :
workspaceEclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps