# Not able to call javascript and css external files

Tags: javascript, css

i have external java-script and CSS file in my project where i am defining my JS and Styling code, i am calling them through `src` but the browser console says that `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/JS/Javascript.js”`

here is my code Structure

[image: Code Structure]

this is how i am doing it

```
    <link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Javascript.js"></script>
```

**link is calling in head tag**

**script is calling in end of body tag tag**

- I am using Eclipse  2018-09 version

Comment: @cale_b it is not TPS Report it is TPWebReport which is my project name..and what was that link ?

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/" Are you sure your local server is well setup to ping the right root forlder?

Comment: @vincent-decoplus yupp ..but,can i check my local server is well setup or not

Comment: @dheerajkumar Yes that's very simple, click on this "http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/" if it lands on something, it means it's well made. If not, send us the error

Comment: @vincent-decoplus on to my console ?

Comment: no, the message in the middle. If it's "can't reach the server" something like this, you have to redo/verify your server param

Comment: @vincent-d yeh it is redirecting me to my login page

Comment: Ok, so it's not the problem, sorry we had to check ^^

Comment: What happens if you try to access the file directly by navigating to the url of the javascript file?

Comment: I was about to ask the same. Can you click on that please http://localhost:8080/JS/Javascript.js

Comment: @vincent-d http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/JS/Javascript.js *

Comment: @vincent-d `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found` this i got

Comment: @dheerajkumar have you trien Antonelli link or mine?

Comment: @vincent-d on clicking    http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/JS/Javascript.js  and   http://localhost:8080/JS/Javascript.js  i am getting `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`

Comment: try both without the ports ":8080"

Comment: Are you hosting your files from the `dist` folder or are you serving the files from the root folder of the project? Can you see in your web server logs if you are accessing the correct file?

Comment: @Patrick how can i check that?

Comment: Check your logs? I don't know; what web server are you using? It's your machine, you tell me ;)

Comment: @vincent-d without portno it is redirecting me to my stackoverflow question

Comment: @Patrick web server log means on my browser console?

Comment: @dheerajkumar what?! o_o How? You tried localhost/TPWebReport/JS/Javascript.js and localhost/JS/Javascript.js ? And it goes to stackoverflow? I'm speechless lol

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @vincent-d ohh sorry its says  `Unable to connect`

Comment: No, not in your browser. In order to serve javascript files you need a web server. How are you running your project?

Comment: @L.Antonelli  mozila developer version

Comment: @dheerajkumar please, try with another web browser

Comment: @Patrick  using tomcat 9 i am running on server

Comment: oooh.. That's why :o when we asked if you have well setup your server it was underline. You need a webserver (you can use wamp or lamp or mamp or anything easy to configure)

Comment: @L.Antonelli what should i try the link or to run my application on diff browser?

Comment: Okay, so check the logs of tomcat. How is that serving your files? And from what folder? Is the css file loaded? What files are in your build folder?

Comment: @vincent-d no but previously i was using  eclipse mars and this was working fine there

Comment: @dheerajkumar try first with the link

Comment: @L.Antonelli same on the other browser i.e on crome it shows not found

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202253/eclipse-tomcat-how-to-specify-which-folder-is-served-from-the-project) tomcat serves files from the WebContent folder. Try moving the JS folder and css folder in to that folder

Answer (score 2):

You said using 
   `<script src="./JS/javascript.js></script>`
didn't work, so I would double check that your root folder and the code match i.e. double check capitalization/name.

I would also recommend trying to move the js file to a new folder and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Comment: you saying to create another folder with diff name just like i have created JS